# I am having custom ListView having two textviews and one button i want to launch another activity on every button click in row?

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

i want when button is clicked in a row it will launch another activity which will show the detail of specific row.!
How to set Listener on button for each row.

Main Activity:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] friendList = {"Javad","Usama","Umar","Bilal","Bhutta sb","Zain Ul Abidin"};

    ListAdapter listAdapter = new CustomClass(this,friendList);
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);



    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {

            String name = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: inside onItemClick() use if(view=R.id.BUTTONID){ start new Activity }

Answer (score 0):

Inside onItemClick

```
if(view=R.id.ButtonID)
{ 
launch new Activity
 }
```

Comment: you can use switch or if else . 
positon = 0 means first button clicked so launch first activity same with other buttons

Answer (score 0):

you can bind button click listener in adapter not in onItemClick
before return view in a getView method.If you don't understand this answer then put your custom adapter code

```
      @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater myCustomInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            View customView = myCustomInflater.inflate(row, parent, false);
            String singleFoodItem = getItem(position);
            TextView itemText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            ImageView buckysImage = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            itemText.setText(singleFoodItem);
Button button = customView.findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(position == 0){
                  //go for next activity
                }
            }
        });
            itemText.setText(singleFoodItem);
            buckysImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.doctorcartoon);
            return customView;
        }
```

Comment: @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater myCustomInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View customView = myCustomInflater.inflate(row, parent, false);
        String singleFoodItem = getItem(position);
        TextView itemText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        ImageView buckysImage = (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        itemText.setText(singleFoodItem);
        buckysImage.setImageResource(R.mipmap.doctorcartoon);
        return customView;
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String[] friendList = {"Javad","Usama","Umar","Bilal","Bhutta sb","Zain Ul Abidin"};

    ListAdapter listAdapter = new CustomClass(this,friendList);
    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);



    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {

            String name = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            Intent i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("selectedValue",friendList[position]);
            startActivity(i);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

in second activity under OnCreate

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null)
{
    String strData = getIntent().getExtras().getString("selectedValue")
}
```